# Resent-From email header on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

I set the "Resent-From" header of an outgoing email.

```
message.setHeader("Resent-From","test@test.com");
```

This should be supported in 1.7.1, but the header is not present in the received email.
I also tried to use a valid admin address (as required for the "From" field) but had no success.

Has anybody successfully set the "Resent-From" header in GAE?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can replicate what you report. However, I can also confirm you that you can set the headers if you use the low level API.

I suggest you to file a ticket on http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list. I will create an internal one.

Comment: Thank you. I added an issue. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8014